# Прерываются данные от сенсора после блокировки устройства

Tags: android

Друзья, добрый день!
Буду очень признателен, если поможете советом. Разбирался с темой сенсоров, и в качестве эксперимента, для себя, решил написать простенький шагомер, работающий на базе сенсора STEP_DETECTOR. Все замечательно, вот только он ни в какую не хочет работать при заблокированном экране. Wake lock'ом проблема так же не разрешилась.

В наличии всего два класса - Activity и Service. В activity только пара кнопок по которым стартует и завершается сервис. Вся логика находится в сервисе. 
Собственно, код:

```
import android.app.Notification; 
import android.app.NotificationManager; 
import android.app.PendingIntent; 
import android.app.Service; 
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.hardware.Sensor; 
import android.hardware.SensorEvent; 
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener; 
import android.hardware.SensorManager; 
import android.os.IBinder; 
import android.os.PowerManager; 
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat; 
import android.util.Log; 
import android.widget.Toast; 

import java.util.Arrays; 

public class MyFirstService extends Service implements SensorEventListener { 

    private SensorEventListener sel; 
    private static final String TAG = "MYSERVICE666"; 
    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock; 
    SensorManager sm; 


    public MyFirstService() { 
        super(); 
        Log.d(TAG, "constructor " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
    } 


    @Override 
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { 
        return null; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        super.onCreate(); 
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate" + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 

        acquireWakeLock(); 
    } 


    @Override 
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 



        sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE); 
        Sensor s = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR); 
        sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); 

        NotificationManager myNotif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
        Intent bIntent = new Intent(MyFirstService.this, MainActivity.class); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MyFirstService.this, 0, bIntent, 0); 
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this) 
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha) 
                .setContentTitle("Title") 
                .setContentText("ANything") 
                .setAutoCancel(true) 
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent); 
        Notification notification = builder.build(); 

        this.startForeground(565656, notification); 
        return START_STICKY; 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void onDestroy() { 
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy" + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
        sm.unregisterListener(sel); 
        wakeLock.release(); 
        super.onDestroy(); 
    } 


    public void acquireWakeLock() { 
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE); 
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, 
                "MyWakelockTag"); 
        wakeLock.acquire(); 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) { 
        Log.d(TAG, "onSensorChanged " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + 
                ". SensorEvent - " + Arrays.toString(sensorEvent.values)); 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) { 

    } 
}
```

В манифесте соответствующий wake lock пермишн стоит.

Если телефон вывести из спячки нажатием power, но экран не разлочивать, то сенсор оживает и работает, пока не потухнет экран. Соответственно, выходит, что у меня не работает wakeLock, или в чем проблема?

За показаниями сенсора наблюдаю по логу, в UI пока ничего не выводил.

Comment: Укажите параметры девайса. Чтоб локализовать проблему надо узнать работает ли сервис, работают ли оповещения от других (вообще от каких-нибудь, в частности от акселерометра) сенсоров.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Спасибо за идею для проверки! девайс - Samsung galaxy s4. Сейчас попробовал аналогичный код, но с акселерометром - данные идут, даже без foreground' для сервиса, и без wakeLock'a
Не совсем понимаю, какие из этого делать выводы - сенсор STEP_DETECTOR засыпает аппаратно при блокировке экрана, и ничего с этим не поделать? Или есть еще какие то хитрости для решения проблемы, помимо wakeLock'ов?